# SQL: Dynamically Transposing Column as Row in Chartio

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I would love to have your help transposing this table's column into a row. I am trying to have the Project Names (column 1) each becoming their own column header with the MUVs value entered as the column value.

I have read through 20+ threads on this topic, but they are using different SQL packages and code that I am unable to use.

The ideal solution would modify this query to create the desired query output:

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT
    cust_gae_account.project_name as "Project Name",
    cust_be_project_usage.unique_visitor_count as "MUVs",
    cust_be_project_usage.billing_period_start as "Month"
FROM
    cust_be_project_usage
INNER JOIN
    cust_gae_account 
    ON cust_gae_account.account_id = cust_be_project_usage.project_id
WHERE
    cust_be_project_usage.admin_account_id = {ACCOUNT_ID}
```

**Current Query Output:**

```
Project Name     |      MUVs       |     Month
-----------------------------------------------------
ProjectAAAAAZ    |      68000      |   Jun 01, 2016
DynamicName      |       3200      |   Jun 01, 2016
ProjectAAAAAZ    |      21000      |   May 01, 2016
DynamicName      |       4500      |   May 01, 2016
CustomProject    |     117000      |   Jun 01, 2016
CustomProject    |     118400      |   May 01, 2016
```

**Desired Query Output:**

```
Project Name     |  CustomProject  |  ProjectAAAAAZ  |  DynamicName  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Jun 01, 2016     |     117000      |      68000      |      3200
May 01, 2016     |     118400      |      21000      |      4500
```

**Notes:**

- We are using PostgreSQL via Chartio, we can only use base SQL
- We cannot use custom functions sadly
- Names and number of projects is dynamic, varies from 1 to 20
- MUVs are always numeric, there are no duplicates

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: We're using PostgreSQL. We cannot use a custom function, only queries unfortunately

Comment: You basically want a pivot table. You could do it with `crosstab` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html but it outputs a table of a static width, with predefined columns and types. You will need to do this outside of the DB.

OR, create a dynamic query, and execute it using `EXECUTE`

Answer (score 0):

You can use crosstab https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html , but it will only work with a static list of columns. So you need a dynamic query. You need to define that query, and execute it.

```
EXECUTE ('SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    \'SELECT
        cust_be_project_usage.billing_period_start as "Month",
        cust_gae_account.project_name as "Project Name",
        cust_be_project_usage.unique_visitor_count as "MUVs"
    FROM
        cust_be_project_usage
    INNER JOIN
        cust_gae_account 
        ON cust_gae_account.account_id = cust_be_project_usage.project_id
    WHERE
        cust_be_project_usage.admin_account_id = {ACCOUNT_ID}\',
    \'SELECT
        cust_gae_account.project_name as "Project Name"
    FROM
        cust_be_project_usage
    INNER JOIN
        cust_gae_account 
        ON cust_gae_account.account_id = cust_be_project_usage.project_id
    WHERE
        cust_be_project_usage.admin_account_id = {ACCOUNT_ID}\')
AS ( "Project Name" date, ' || 
    (SELECT
        string_agg(cust_gae_account.project_name, ' int,')
    FROM
        cust_be_project_usage
    INNER JOIN
        cust_gae_account 
        ON cust_gae_account.account_id = cust_be_project_usage.project_id
    WHERE
        cust_be_project_usage.admin_account_id = {ACCOUNT_ID}) || ' int'
|| ' )')
```

I am not able to test it though. It SHOULD work, but my suspicions are that it might not, in these situations:

1. Concatenating to a scalar formed by a query (might need to use a variable for that one)
2. I might have mixed up a column somewhere
3. Not sure how you pass the `{ACCOUNT_ID}` parameter so you might need to change that too

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you so much for taking the time to answer this. When I run the query I get a syntax error at the first open parenthesis (after Execute)

Comment: Try to do it without the brackets then. I will try to run it on an actual DB later today.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I tried removing the brackets and reformatting the query. I kept running into errors. Any help of yours would be huge!